# firebase deploy only function not recognizing any of my functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to deploy a single cloud function while debugging using the following command:

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions:trig-users-onUserUpdate
```

But I get this error:

```
i  functions: current functions in project: trig-auth-createAuthUser(us-central1), trig-auth-onDeleteUser(us-central1), trig-users-onUserUpdate(us-central1)
⚠  functions: the following filters were specified but do not match any functions in the project: trig-users-onUserUpdate
```

When I do deploy all functions I see it in the list:

```
✔  functions[trig-users-onUserUpdate(us-central1)]: Successful update operation.
```

I tried adding the `(us-central1)` but I get this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The region doesn't count as part of the name of the function for deployment.  There could be a bug in the Firebase CLI.  I suggest upgrading to the latest, then posting a bug report here:  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson I was already at v8.1.1 but re-ran `npm install -g firebase-tools` in case and still no luck. Should I try un-installing and re-installing completely? Could it be a nvm version issue?

Comment: nvm doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with modules/directories that are imported.

In my case, my `index.js` was structured like so:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

const users = require('./triggers/users')
const posts = require('./triggers/posts')
const triggers = {
    users,
    posts
}

exports.trig = triggers
```

To make it work, replace the `-` that firebase adds in the name with `.` and it works so:

```
// WRONG
$ firebase deploy --only functions:trig-users-onUserUpdate
// RIGHT
$ firebase deploy --only functions:trig.users.onUserUpdate
```

See discussion with the team here: [github polish](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2166)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this seems to be not an error, but warning. It is appearing when you trying to deploy function and there firebase is not able to find code of the function you are mentioning in the filter. ex. I have one function deployed(`postCache`) and i tried exactly the same command in my environment (without any code) I get following output:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: current functions in project: postCache(us-central1)
⚠  functions: the following filters were specified but do not match any functions in the project: trig-users-onUserUpdate
✔  scheduler: all necessary APIs are enabled
✔  Deploy complete!
```

This means that you already have deployed function of that name, but command is not able to find new code to deploy.

I would check if there is no spelling mistake in function name in your code or if you running the command from proper directory.

I hope this will help!

Comment: I just tried by adding a `console.log` in a trigger and it didn't show up in the logs unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter what was changed in the function, I think Firebase SDK is not able to find source code to implement the function...